# Add a line to survminer survival plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival

I have the following survival curve

```
require("survival")
library(survminer)
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = lung)
ggsurvplot(fit,  palette = "jco",risk.table = TRUE)
```

I would like to add to the plot the non-straight line with x `time=c(0,100, 200, 300, 500, 750)` and y `surv=c(1, 0.99, 0.95, 0.92, 0.88, 0.82)`

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this yet?

Comment: Unfortunately none

Answer (score 0):

I think you're  looking for the geom_curve() OR geom_segment() argument - you'll have to specify the type of curve, but it's certainly one option for adding a customized line to your ggplot.

Here's more: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_segment.html